# How can I creat a buttonBar that scrolls to the side like YouTube's filters?

Tags: flutter

How can I creat a buttonBar that scrolls to the sideways like YouTube's filters?

[[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for (as I've never seen these filters on YT), but I would assume you can simply create this by using the `ListView()`-Widget.

```
ListView(
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 160.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 160.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 160.0,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 160.0,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 160.0,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

For an example, just look [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list) at the flutter docs

To get the style for the list elements you've mentioned in your example, just use a Container with [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) (color, border, borderRadius).
When you want to make actual buttons out of this, wrap your created container with this:

```
Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: tapHandler,
    splashColor: splashColor,
    highlightColor: highlightColor,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
    child: child,
  ),
)
```

Just replace the variables with your own values.

Comment: That helps, thankyou. how would you add spacing to it?

Comment: If you mean the space between the list elements, just use margin.